# In the following generalized regression model, why am I getting an error with one column and not with the other column if both are similar?

Tags: r, debugging, regression, glm

I have the following data frame and fitting models:

```
goyo <- data.frame(
  Grade <- c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8),
  a <- c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  b <- c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
goyo$Grade <- factor(goyo$Grade)
glm(reformulate(c("Grade"), "a"), family=binomial, data = goyo)
glm(reformulate(c("Grade"), "b"), family=binomial, data = goyo)
```

when I run the fitting model with column "b" I get the error:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

It looks like it has to do with the number of levels. However, both columns look virtually the same and I do not understand what is the difference between them that makes them give different result.

Answer (score 0):

`glm(b ~ Grade)` deletes missings according to

```
> goyo[complete.cases(goyo[c('Grade', 'b')]), ]
   Grade  a b
1      8 NA 0
9      8 NA 0
14     8  1 0
18     8  1 1
21     8 NA 1
23     8 NA 0
```

and no contrasts can be applied to Grade, which explains the

```
> glm(reformulate(c("Grade"), "b"), family=binomial, data = goyo)
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Check `goyo[complete.cases(goyo[c('Grade', 'a')]), ]`, it's different with `a ~ Grade`.

BTW, wouldn't it make more sense to regress grade on b?

```
> reformulate(termlabels="b", response="Grade")
Grade ~ b
```